# Не могу загрузить свою модель в playcanvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

PlayCanvas имеет возможность встраивания в веб-страницы и я решил опробовать этот функционал. Кубик, данный по-умолчанию в туториале, крутился наотлично, однако, когда я попробовал загрузить свою модель, в консоли выдало:

```
Error loading model: assets/model.obj
[TypeError: cannot read property 'clone' of null]
```

Я пробовал с другими форматами (dae и fbx, про которые было написано в документации), однако на них консоль ругалась той же ошибкой. Вот код импорта и подгрузки модели на холст:

```js
// add model asset
var asset = new pc.Asset("amodel", "model", {
  url: "assets/fuck.obj"
})
app.assets.add(asset)
var modelAsset = app.assets.find("amodel", "model")

// create box entity
var cube = new pc.Entity('cube');
cube.addComponent('model', {
  type: "asset",
  asset: modelAsset
});
```

Какие могут быть варианты решения этой проблемы? Заранее спасибо.